# How do I make a dialog button send to a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I just want the button to, rather than close dialog, link to another page (or both is fine too)

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Install",
        tabIndex: -1,
        width: "340",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: By "link to another page", do you mean open another page? Do you mean display a link?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
```

becomes

```
$( document ).get(0).href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
```

use

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```